# How do you remove duplicates values in 2d

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-D to list that i would like to remove duplicates but still keep the order in list by using a list comprehension. For example here is my list below

```
Df = [[2,4,6,6,7],[3,4,5,7,9,3,5],[2,4,6,8]]
```

I would like my result to be

```
Df2 = [[2,4,6,7],[3,4,5,7,9,],[2,4,6,8]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it if order is not important

```
Df2 = [list(set(item)) for item in Df]
```

If the order is important, try the code below

```
from collections import OrderedDict
Df2 = [list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(item)) for item in Df]
```

**Input**

`Df = [[2,4,6,6,7],[3,4,5,7,9,3,5],[2,4,6,8]]`

**Output1**

`Df2 = [[2, 4, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 7, 9], [8, 2, 4, 6]]`

**Output2**

`Df2 =[[2, 4, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]`

Comment: This works but if there's no duplicates in the list the order is not in order. I updated the question in the description

Comment: While the idea is good, you're relying on an implementation detail of some versions of CPython here. `set` is still [specified as unordered](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). You cannot ensure this will work in any and all implementations. You'd need an OrderedSet or help yourself with an OrderedDict to guarantee it always works.

Comment: @blubberdiblub thanks for the hint. Code updated to keep the order as well.